# NSString substring

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am parsing an XML and get the 2 values like target: $1,000 and received:$500 . Now values are in string format including the "$" symbol. I used substring and get the value say 500. Now I have to calculate the percentage of it say, its 50% of target ($1000).

But I am confused due to arbitrary length of received amount means how can I calculate the percentage when received amount for example $50 or $500 or $5,000 ?

How can I remove the " $ " and " , " symbols from both target and received ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 NSString *str=@"$5,000";
 NSString *str1=[[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""] retain];
 NSString *final=[[str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""] retain];
```

// release str1 and final when finished using them.

try this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

NSString extension:

```
@implementation NSString (DeleteCharacters)
- (NSString *)stringByDeletingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)cs {
    NSArray *array = [self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs];
    return [array componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
@end
```

And use it to delete unneeded characters:

```
[string stringByDeletingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"$,"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the $ is easy, just use string replace:

```
 NSString *temp = [@"$100" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""];
```

You could also do the for the ,

Comment: Something has been dropped in your answer, is'nt it ?

Comment: Really?, Where. I did not include the , because I thought it would be self explanatory.

Comment: LOL ! Ah, OK, I did'nt realize that you meant ",". I thought that the end of the last sentence was missing :-)

Answer (score 2):

`[stringContains$ stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"$"]];` this line is useful to remove the $ symbol

Comment: Not so for the comma. It will even fail with the $ if you have some stray leading whitespace.